# Redirect to login page automatically after some time

Tags: java, jsp, redirect

How can we redirect to login page automatically after some time?

I have a requirement to redirect to login page if the current page is idle for 10 minutes in Java/JSP.

I tried to use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120;url=./login.html">` tag. This works only when I click on any link but not automatically after 2 mins(120secs).

Can anyone tell me how to redirect to  login page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Is it Java? No... But you must use PHP or JavaScript

JavaScript:

```
<script>
 //   setTimeout("window.location.href='login.html';",time);
 //example:

    setTimeout("window.location.href='login.html';",120); // after 2 minutes
</script>
```

Add this code in HTML.head (<html><head>...here...</head>...)

Answer (score 0):

Using servlet, you can try this :

```
response.setHeader("Refresh","120;url=./login.html");
```

But I do not think that's what you want. In fact, for your needs, you need more than just redirect, you need to :

- Invalidate the session OR make a session-timeout ;
- Filter your ressources so they'll not be accessed unless login is successful.

---

As for ***invalidation*** from servlet :

```
public LogoutServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(...) {
       request.getSession().invalidate();
    }
}
```

A code that I shamelessly copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004417/servlet-session-invalidate), look into the thread, few good infos there.

---

As for the ***session-timeout*** (check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/how-to-configure-the-session-timeout-in-servlet/)):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(2*60);
```

Which you may combime with a :

```
response.sendRedirect("./login.html");
```

---

The other way of doing things is a filter, ***filtering*** is a technology that protects your ressources ; it's just a servlet of which you override the `doFilter` methode. So, inside that `doFilter`, you can set the session-timeout and redirect, invalidate the session, etc. check this [tuto](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html), it does have a "***Servlet and JSP Filters***" section you could enjoy.

Best of luck.